# Texto da fila de análises limpa foi revertido para o inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

O texto da fila de análises limpa foi revertido para o inglês, tal como mostra a imagem:

<kbd>[image: Reverted to English]</kbd>

[Editado] Dias depois, a correção é parcial:

<kbd>[image: Still in English]</kbd>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recriei com base numa sugestão do transifex. Desta vez ele foi esperto. [Link da tradução](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/131532879?q=queue+has+been+cleared). Agora precisa algum CM liberar lá, e entra no ar no build/deploy seguinte.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: [Traduzido](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english/131532897?q=want+to+get+back+to+the+questions), agora é todo o processo de novo....

Comment: @bfavaretto não entendo, por quê isso ocorre? Displicência da SE com outros sites da rede? Se uma string já foi traduzida e ao commitarem algo novo reverte a tradução, eles só estão tornando inútil e trabalhoso o belissimo trabalho de vocês, tradutores. Não tem alguma forma de comunicar isso a eles? É realmente irritante ver isso acontecer, apesar de não traduzir por não dominar o idioma, eu fico bastante irritado vendo o trabalho da comunidade ser tratado dessa forma pela SE.

Comment: @Articuno Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64589

Comment: @VictorStafusa Correção no ar já